# Do I use $stateProvider or $routeProvider for a single page app with log in seperation

Tags: angularjs, state, route-provider

Do I use  $stateProvider or  $routeProvider for signle page app with log in seperation, ie you have to be authenticated to see and access certain views?

I've started with this:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signIn', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signIn.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signUp', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signUp.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

so lets see I have this view that needs logged in and another that needs to be logged in with a certain privilege, what is the correct and best practice approach?

```
 .when('/protected', {
                templateUrl: 'views/protected.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
 .when('/protectedAndHasAuth', {
                templateUrl: 'views/protectedAndHasAuth.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try $stateProvider if you have complex view .

I mean if you want to split your view further  ,

For example

```
.state('mainview', {
 url: '/main',
 access: 1,
 views: {
  '@': {
   templateUrl: 'mainview.html',
   controller: 'MainviewController'
  },
  'subview1@mainview': {
   templateUrl: 'subview1.html',
   controller: 'subview1Controller'
  },
  'subview2@mainview': {
   templateUrl: 'subview2.html',
   controller: 'subview2Controller'
  },
 }
})
```

Then you can go with $stateProvider

[Angular routing](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-start-with-angular.html)

Comment: would routeProvider work to secure login access only pages if no nesting of views is needed

Comment: i dont know what you mean by secure login access , if that is related to security then you need server + client side logic , generating authentication id , hashing etc

Comment: basically I mean that the application route provider will only allow navigation to a view if the user is logged in, handled by another angular module

Comment: yes ,you can write some conditions like if( $location.path() == '/login' && AuthService.isLoggedIn() )
   {
    $location.path('/'); 
   } don't allow user to go to login if they are logged in,you can try somthing like this in your controller

Comment: where do you put the logic for **if( $location.path()** in the controller?